# A rarely mentioned fact about perfect powers

Tags: arithmetic, perfect-powers

It is easy to see that for each [perfect power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_power) $N = n^k$ it holds that

$$N-1 = (n-1)\sum_{0\leq i<k} n^{i}$$

It is not much harder to see that for each $x < N$ there are $a_i < n$ such that

$$x = \sum_{0\leq i<k} a_i\ n^{i}$$

What makes perfect powers perfect bases for the redundancy-free representation of numbers $x<N$ is that there is a perfect 1:1 correspondence between all $x<N$ and all k-tuples $\{a_i\}$ with $a_i<n$.

I wonder why these - as I find important - facts are not more often prominently mentioned, e.g. in the [Wikipedia article on perfect powers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_power).

Comment: Whenever we write a natural number in base $n$ we use this representation...I'd say it was extremely well known.

Comment: I know that. But this was not the question. You can use *any* number *k* for *k*-ary representation. But perfect powers are special because they allow redundancy-free representations.

Comment: Isn't this simply representation in radix $n$? What am I missing? And what's the question? “Why somebody didn't mention this?” is not a question that can receive an answer other than “they didn't deem it important”.

Comment: @egreg: I added a note on "redundancy-free" which probably makes perfect powers "important".

Comment: And what do you mean by “redundancy-free”? I think that you're saying that every number less than $n^k$ can be expressed with at most $ k$ digits in base $n$, which is obvious. Also the converse is obvious: every $k$-digit number in base $n$ is less than $n^k$.

Comment: @egreg He means that the representation is unique, rather than each representation themselves carrying no redundancy. For example, $N - 1$ has a lot of redundancy $a_1 = a_2 = \dots = a_k $.

Comment: @HansStricker This has nothing to do with perfect powers; it's simply a property of representation in base $n$.

Comment: A property that perfect powers do possess and other numbers do not.